# min and max in form shows an error angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make validate form in my project.
when user enter number less than 6 and bigger than 120 so it shows an error.
I got this error also

```
Error: ngModel:numfmt
```

Model is not of type `number

[image]
I tried to do that (updated)

it's not working

Comment: what is it?  I never heard about this regex...

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `ng-minlength`
  `ng-maxlength` instead of only `min` and `max` bcz `min` `max` is only for `input` tag

See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea)

Comment: I looked there before they use min,max directive. not ng-min, ng max.

Comment: `Like min, sets the min validation error key if the value entered is less than ngMin, but does not trigger HTML5 native validation. Takes an expression.`

Comment: yes, it not works man. I also get this error "Error: ngModel:numfmt
Model is not of type `number`"

Comment: bro  i think `min` `max` is only applicable for `input` tag u are applying on `textarea`

Comment: yes but i try ng-min and ng-max and it's not works even.

Comment: i update my answer plz try and let me know if still not works :) @AdirZoari

Comment: I updated my post, you can see please. it still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150292/discussion-between-adir-zoari-and-kishan-oza).